# Como destruir una sesion con jsp

Tags: tomcat

Hola amigos que tal me gustaria me resolvieran una duda con jsp y servlets, como podria destruir un inicio de sesion con servlet para una pagina web?

Answer (score 0):

Esto obtiene las variables de sesión creadas y las elimina.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Si controlas el inicio de sesión con una variable esta es la forma más sencilla. En cualquier caso, si pudieramos ver tu código y como validas que el usuario está logado podremos dar una respuesta más adecuada.